# Taking screenshots of yakuake sessions in another session

Tags: screenshot, yakuake

I am using yakuake, and am running multiple sessions. is there any (hopefully easy) way to grab a screenshot of all the sessions by using another terminal (say konsole or ssh)?
or is there an alternative of yakuake (like guake) that i could use?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ok, got it, by using qdbus:

```
#/bin/bash

# clear first old screenshots 
rm screenshot_*.png

# helper from https://github.com/aplatanado/yakuake-session
function yakuake_showwindow() {
    local wid=$(wmctrl -xl | grep -iF 'yakuake.yakuake' | head -n1 | cut -d' ' -f1)
    if [[ -z "$wid" ]]; then
        qdbus org.kde.yakuake /yakuake/window toggleWindowState > /dev/null
    else
        wmctrl -i -a $wid
    fi
}

# make sure yakuake is visible
yakuake_showwindow

# caputer all sessions
s=0
for x in `qdbus org.kde.yakuake /yakuake/sessions terminalIdList | sed -e 's/,/ /g'`; do 
    let "s++"
    #echo $s $x 
    qdbus org.kde.yakuake /yakuake/sessions raiseSession $x; 
    import -window root -resize 1920x1080  screenshot_$s.png
done
```